# What is the use of a laptop screen opened 180 degrees?

Tags: laptop, display

The screen of my laptop opens up to 180 degrees (but not more). I wonder if there is a special purpose for this angle?

[image]

Comment: I have one like that and I sometimes rotate it 180 degrees then I can stand it up against something and use a USB keyboard  & mouse as if the screen was a monitor.

Comment: If I lend the laptop to a clumsy idiot, they may not break the hinge so easily by bending the screen back too far.

Comment: My work laptop is a 2 in 1 and you can fold the screen through 360 degrees so it's like a tablet, or a bit less and stand it up nicely. More degrees is better.

Answer (score 2):

A picture is worth a thousand words :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fully open laptop to 180 degrees in vertical position.

[image]